# How to restrict tenants in multitenant application with Azure AD authentication

Tags: azure, single-page-application, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I'm currently developing a multitenant Angular SPA application that connects to multiple webAPI's in the backend and uses AzureAD authentication where each AD represents a tenant.

Azure documentation on multitenancy points to an example applicaiton called [Tailpsin.Surveys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/run-the-app) which I was able to run after following the steps on the page. That application differs from my scenario as it is a WebApp no an SPA.

In this webApp, during OpenId middlreware setup, an implementation of `OpenIdConnectEvents` is passed. 
That implementation overrides `TokenValidated` method and blocks tenants that hadn't gone through signup before.

That's what I'm trying to achieve in in my application, but would that mean that each and every WebAPI should always check for issuer claim on token to validate the tenant?

That seems like something repetitive and could turn into a performance issue, I believe.

Is there any configuration in Azure or some other ways of restricting access to your application to a set of defined tenants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such setting in Azure Active Directory. The options around 'tenancy' are multi-tenant or single-tenant. Multi-tenant means that technically all tenants could get an access token for your service.

For your specific scenario, I believe you would want your service to keep a whitelist of tenants which are allowed to call your API, and check that the token has the correct `issuer` or `tid` claim. You mention that you think this check might be a performance issue, but you are already checking every token that the `aud` claim is correct, and that the token is signed by Azure AD, and checking the `scope`/`role` claims in the token for permissions, so checking an additional claim should not really add significant overhead.